# Swift / How to hide NavigationBar with Root View Controller / Page View Controller. Little gap on top of screen

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the [SwipeViewController](https://github.com/fortmarek/SwipeViewController).

It's a sub class of `UINavigationController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate`

The view is instantiated within the AppDelegate.Swift by:

```
    let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    let navigationController = ViewController(rootViewController: pageController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The **complete** code of the ViewController is:

```
import UIKit
import SwipeViewController

class ViewController: SwipeViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationBar.hidden = true

        let VC1 = UIViewController()
        VC1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.36, blue: 0.60, alpha: 1.0)
        VC1.title = "Recent"
        let VC2 = UIViewController()
        VC2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.70, green: 0.23, blue: 0.92, alpha: 1.0)
        VC2.title = "Random"

        setViewControllerArray([VC1, VC2])
        setFirstViewController(0)

    }
}
```

My problem is, once the App is started, no matter if in simulator or physical device. There is a gap in the exact height of the status bar.

[image]

Once I press on the screen, the view "moves up".

[image]

Also. For only one time I'm able to grab the view and grab it down. Then the screen will "run back" to the top (like in a graphic bug) and from that moment on, till next App start, the screen is "locked" to the window. A condition I want all the time....

[image]

What is the best practise to delete those "bugs", have the NavigationBar hidden and the views locked to the window? Help is very appreciated.

PS. If I don't hide the NavigationBar, there is no bug at all.

PPS. You can download the sample project from the provided github link. It's exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The following function has to be overwritten in the UINavigationController Subclass (SwipeViewController.swift).

```
    override public func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();

    if self.view.frame.size.height == UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height {
        for childVC in childViewControllers {
            childVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, navigationBar.frame.size.height, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - navigationBar.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`, it will execute the code before the finish creating the view

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

This is added since In iOS 9, XCode 7, Swift 2.0

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: with `self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true` in `viewWillAppear` I have a black screen AND a grey navigation bar. with `navigationBar.hidden = true` in `viewWillAppear` have no bar but only a black screen

Comment: ps. the sample project from the provided github link is exactly what i'm dealing with right now to test.

Comment: sorry i forgot that `prefersStatusBarHidden`. hope this will help

Comment: is your `ViewController` embeded with navigation controller? please share part of storyboard for ViewController. thanks

Comment: there is no storyboard. `class RootVC: SwipeViewController {` is instantiated within the AppDelegate and the 2 existing ViewController are instantiated within the `viewDidLoad` of RootVC

Comment: as said in my open post. SwipeViewController is a sub class of `UINavigationController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate`

Answer (score 2):

To solve the similar problem I've created singleton class to implement UINavigationControllerDelegate. And implemented following method:

```
public func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
if (viewController.isMemberOfClass:(YourUIViewControllesSubclass1.self)){
    //or another detection
    navigationController.navigatonBarHidden = true//or false if needed
} else if (viewController.isMemberOfClass:(YourUIViewControllesSubclass2.self)){
    navigationController.navigatonBarHidden = true//or false if needed
}/ ... may check others
```

I wish it would solve the problem

Comment: i don't really get it. first of all, I get an error at the ":" at `.isMemberOfClass:(YourUIViewCont` then: were do i put this function in and where do i call it?

Comment: i'm sorry for my wrong translation from objc, that i use. in this method your goal is to identify the viewController and  set navigationBarHidden = true or false

Comment: it is a delegate method of UINavigationController. navigationController will call this method before every of its viewControllers apears

Comment: don't worry, i got the code running.. and in what class do i write this function? some helper class? and where do i use it at?

Comment: i see. so i don't have to call it. i will try it

Comment: yes, sort of  of helper. initialize it where you initialize navigationController (in AppDelegate, i think)